# Debugging Release (without symbols) in gdb, but with source build folder (.o files)?

Tags: gdb

There is an application I've built from source, which works for the most part fine, but for a certain problem I've encountered recently, it warrants a trip down the debugger.

However, the problem is that the build takes an hour or more, and I've already built this application in release, meaning `gdb` says "(no debugging symbols found)...done.".

I can still set function breakpoints in `gdb` with the executable as is, except I cannot step through code ("Single stepping until exit from function ... , which has no line number information. ; Cannot find bounds of current function").

So, given that I have the sources and a source build folder full of `.o` files, - in the interest of not having to waste potentially several hours on building a debug version - I was wondering if it is possible to somehow instruct `gdb` to use these files/directories, to then let me step through the code?

Comment: You should have created the release build with separate debug files. Have a look at https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was wondering if it is possible to somehow instruct gdb to use these files/directories, to then let me step through the code?

Yes.

First, you need to prepare a *matching* copy of the functions you want to step through, but with debug info.

Suppose you have `foo()` and `bar()` in `foo.o` and `bar.o` respectively. You need to rebuild them with *all original flags, and* `-g` added:

```
rm -f foo.o bar.o
make foo.o bar.o CFLAGS="$ORIGINAL_FLAGS -g"
```

Next you need to figure out where `foo()` and `bar()` are located:

```
nm -A foo.o bar.o | egrep ' (foo|bar)$'
```

Finally you need to use GDB `add-symbol-file foo.o $ADDR_foo_o` and `add-symbol-file bar.o $ADDR_bar_o` to enjoy your source debugging.

Computing `$ADDR_foo_o` is somewhat tricky: you need

- the address of `foo` inside `foo.o` (a1) (output from `nm` above),
- the address of `.text` in `foo.o` (a2, use `readelf -WS foo.o | grep '\.text$'`),
- the address of `foo` in the main binary (a3, use `nm a.out | grep ' foo$'`).

I believe you need `$ADDR_foo_o = $a3 - $a1 + $a2`.

For a position-independent executable, you'll also need to add `a.out` relocation (a4), which you can find from `info file` or `info proc mappings`.

P.S. In order to avoid this pain, you should *always* build your release binaries with `-g` flag (which is orthogonal to optimization flags), and use `strip -g a.out -o a.out-for-deployment`. Then keep `a.out` for debugging, and deploy the stripped version to production / customers.

Comment: Ah, that is awesome, thanks a lot - there's still rebuilding, but I don't need to rebuild the *entire* source `:)`. Thanks again!

Comment: @sdaau I've updated the answer for position-independent executable -- there is an extra relocation to be added in that case.