# How to get debug information (like line number) by coredump

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, gdb, coredump

I'm debugging a rarely happening SIGSEGV prod issue (language C++), which happens once every hundreds of times running. I tried to enable the corefile and send it to GCS.

My steps to debug:

1. Build the source code with same compilation and link option as prod environment.
2. Both executables contain `-g3`, which enables debug symbol.
3. `gdb <binary> <corefile>`

What I expect is a stacktrace with line number, but in reality only address and function is displayed.

Some thing like

```
#0  0x00005635c6335f99 in file::tensorflow::CurlHttpRequest::CurlHttpRequest(file::tensorflow::LibCurl*, file::tensorflow::env::Env*, std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >) ()

#1  0x00005635c5c86e46 in file::tensorflow::CurlHttpRequest::CurlHttpRequest(file::tensorflow::LibCurl*, std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > const&) ()
<omit further stacktrace>
```

I'm wondering if I have a way to get the line number as well?

Comment: Is tensorflow/curl also built with debug symbols?

Comment: @ssbssa Yes. I use bazel, and build option `bazel build --copt="-g3" <target>` is passed down to all translation units.

Comment: Well, it looks like `-g3` is NOT passed down, otherwise it would show the source/line info.

Comment: Try `readelf --debug-dump=info <binary> | grep "DW_AT_producer"` to see all compiler options that were used during compilation and `-g3` in particular.

Comment: Side note; for debugging rare crashes I personally find [rr](https://rr-project.org/) to be very helpful, as you can replay the same run over and over and also step backwards through the execution.

Answer (score 1):

> Build the source code with same compilation and link option as prod environment.

I think you mean that you've tried to *rebuild* the executable from the same source, but with debug options. In other words, the `core` and the executable you are trying to debug no longer match.

While such rebuilding *sometimes* produces a close-enough binary, this is *by no means* guaranteed -- you can get a binary which will produce completely bogus stack trace this way.

The best practice is described in the "P.S." section [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53873609/50617).

> I'm wondering if I have a way to get the line number as well?

The frames you show are inside the TensorFlow library. I suspect that you are not getting file/line info here because you are using pre-built `libtensorflow`. You would need to rebuild that library from source with `-g3` as well.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply! I built the source always with the same compilation, both with `-g3`

Comment: > I suspect that you are not getting file/line info here because you are using pre-built libtensorflow
I'm using bazel as my build system, and I'm sure I'm building from scratch (since patch would lead to recompilation and takes loooooong time)

Comment: @Tinyden `bazel` can have custom flags applied to certain packages. I suspect there is a `copts = ["-g0"]` _somewhere_ in a `BUILD` or a `.bzl` file.